# Cannot invoke dataTaskWithRequest with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I get a weird error in my iOS swift app. The compiler complains at the first row of:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    self.oauthManager.customOAuth2Manager.parseData(data, response: response, error: error, body:request, callback: { (jsonArray, error) -> Void in
    })
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithRequest' with an argument list of type '(NSURLRequest, (_, _, _) -> _)'
```

However, it's not on that row the error seems to be located. If I remove the inner call to `parseData` the error does not appear.

The declaration to `parseData` is:

```
func parseData(data: NSData, response:NSURLResponse, error:NSError?, body:String?, callback:JsonRequestCallback)
```

where `JsonRequestCallback` is:

```
public typealias JsonRequestCallback = (jsonArray: NSArray?, error: NSError?) -> Void
```

Also:

```
let request = oauthManager.newLoginRequest(emailOrCompanyCode: emailOrCompanyCode, password: password) as NSURLRequest
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
```

and

```
func newLoginRequest(var #emailOrCompanyCode: String, var password:String?) -> NSMutableURLRequest
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Pass String to 'body:' parameter. You have passed 'request'.

Comment: Thanks! Such simple misstake and so misleading error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, Satachito was correct. Just an invalid parameter. Unfortunately the Swift compiler does not specify the exact error, not the correct line for this.

So for others having similar issues, look for misstakes in all code in any passed closures