# Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithRequest' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableURLRequest, (_, _, _) throws -> _)'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After start using Swift 2 in Xcode 7 Beta, I get an error `cannot invoke`. What cause this issue?

I try to figure out my problem by following these 2 questions, but i still get the error: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103902/cannot-invoke-datataskwithrequest-with-an-argument-list-of-type), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647406/how-to-use-completionhandler-closure-with-return-in-swift)

**Error:**

> Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithRequest' with an argument list of type
>   '(NSMutableURLRequest, (_, _, _) throws -> _)'

**Complete Code**

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {data, response, error in
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {
                let resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String

                if(resultValue=="Success"){

                    //Store Confimed Account Detail Inside Core Data
                    try self.saveAccountDetail(userloginTextField!, confirmDataRetrieve: 0)

                    //Login is Successful
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Leo Dabus, with his help I figure out that this is the new feature in Swift 2. the way you type in the code should be to `try` or `try!` Handling

NSJSONSerialization should be run: (if is throwing input your remove the `!`)

```
let json = try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: From the documentation : Sometimes you know a throwing function or method won’t, in fact, throw an error at runtime. On those occasions, you can write try! before the expression to disable error propagation and wrap the call in a runtime assertion that no error will be thrown. If an error actually is thrown, you’ll get a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

Change from `try` to `try!` Then it will start compiling as norm.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,
    completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let data = data {
            println(data.length)
            // you can use data here
        } else if let error = error {
            println(error.description)
        }
})
task!.resume()
```

you can test with this one

```
let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(
    NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg")!),
    completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let data = data {
            println(data.length)
            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                println(image.description)
            }

        } else if let error = error {
            println(error.description)
        }

})
task!.resume()
```

Comment: Now i get error `Extra argument "completionHandler" in call`

Comment: Now i get this error `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'`

Comment: Everything was working fine, until I convert it. How can i run the convert again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80098/discussion-between-brian-s-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: i have already downloaded the beta 7 but I haven't open it. I will try to open a sample project and fix the syntax for you

Comment: Well this is what happened to me :) i hope everything goes well for you

Comment: I think the best think is to keep using the app store version unless you really need the new stuff

Comment: I figure it out is the new Swift 2